# Items inside Tikz environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, lists, itemize

I have a tikz environment in which I have a long text to write. The problem is that it gets too big horizontally so I would like to breakdown in items. In the example below, is like if I want to have each set of list elements to be in their respective row (list11, list12,list13 in row 1, list21, list22, list23 in row 3, and so on).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[line width=2pt] (0,0) -- (7,0)node[right=4mm]{};
\draw[line width=1pt] (0,-2mm)node[below](0){\strut Given $list_{11},list_{12},list_{13}$, $list_{21},list_{22},list_{23}$} -- (0,2mm)node[above] {$i$ is drawn};
\draw[line width=1pt] (7,-2mm)node[below](0){\strut Given $list_{11},list_{12},list_{13}$, $list_{21},list_{22},list_{23}.$} -- (7,2mm)node[above]{$i$ is drawn};
\draw[-latex] (0,-7mm) -- +(0,-10mm)node[below]{$xx,yy,zz$};
\draw[-latex] (7,-7mm) -- +(0,-10mm)node[below]{$xx,yy,zz$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Why did you tag this `tikz-trees`?

Comment: In some way, my environment is a "flat" tree and I thought people that work with trees would be interested in using align functions in this environment, @cfr.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the option `align=center` to center-align node text when multiple lines are used, and add `\\` before the second row elements. Also, as @egreg has pointed out, it is better to use `\mathit{list}` instead of leaving it in pure math mode like a normal variable name. A new command `\lst{..}` can be quite handy for this repeated pattern.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\newcommand*{\lst}[1]{\ensuremath{\mathit{list}_{#1}}}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[align=center]
\draw[line width=2pt] (0,0) -- (7,0)node[right=4mm]{};
\draw[line width=1pt] (0,-2mm)node[below](0){Given $\lst{11},\lst{12},\lst{13}$,\\$\lst{21},\lst{22},\lst{23}$} -- (0,2mm)node[above] {$i$ is drawn};
\draw[line width=1pt] (7,-2mm)node[below](1){Given $\lst{11},\lst{12},\lst{13}$,\\$\lst{21},\lst{22},\lst{23}$.} -- (7,2mm)node[above]{$i$ is drawn};
\draw[-latex] (0) -- +(0,-3em)node[below]{$xx,yy,zz$};
\draw[-latex] (1) -- +(0,-3em)node[below]{$xx,yy,zz$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: +1, but probably `$\mathit{list}_{11}$` is better, try it.

Comment: @egreg - Thank you, I have updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\newcommand*{\lst}[1]{\mathit{list}_{#1}}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[line width=2pt] (0,0) -- (7,0)node[right=4mm]{};
\draw[line width=1pt] (0,-2mm)node[below](0){\begin{tabular}{c}
                                                     Given $\lst{11},\lst{12},\lst{13}$\\
                                                     $\lst{21},\lst{22},\lst{23}$
                                                     \end{tabular}} -- (0,2mm)node[above] {$i$ is drawn};
\draw[line width=1pt] (7,-2mm)node[below](1){\begin{tabular}{c}
Given $\lst{11},\lst{12},\lst{13}$,\\
$\lst{21},\lst{22},\lst{23}$.\end{tabular}} -- (7,2mm)node[above]{$i$ is drawn};
\draw[-latex] (0) -- +(0,-3em)node[below]{$xx,yy,zz$};
\draw[-latex] (1) -- +(0,-3em)node[below]{$xx,yy,zz$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```